# Netflix Access Control

Tags: netflix, access-control

Let's say I have this rather, erm, *curious* brother of mine, and on our Netflix subscription, he's been watching *Mythbusters: Biggest Explosions*, *Clifford's Really Big Movie*, *Arrested Development* etc. none of which I, my mom, or my sister really want to let him watch. But he has the remote/mouse/computer, so I can't really stop him (revoking a device from Netflix has an overnight turnaround). Keep in mind, too, that these all have different ratings.

Is there any to block out *individual* shows on Netflix via parental controls?

Comment: Cliffords Really Big Movie is an issue?

Comment: @drachen It's blending pseudo-rock with a humongous red dog, a plot basically straight out of Scooby-Doo, and Clifford with sharp eyebrows. I had bursts of dizziness just watching that scene.

Comment: Ahhhhh, in the future that bit of clarification would help a tad ;)

Answer (score 2):

heaven forbid he is watching MythBusters, he could learn something. As stated, you can't block individual shows. Just revoke the device, change your Netflix account password, and the issue should go away.

Answer (score 0):

Not individual shows, but block certain ratings. Access your account via Netflix.com, and click on "Change parental control setting" in the Preferences section. Note that this will also block you, your mom, and your sister from watching unapproved content (streaming or adding to DVD queue).

EDIT: after re-reading your question about 10 times, I don't think I really understand if this is a genuine question or not.

Comment: After the update comment I think it's totally valid.